# Cut off text before read more

Tags: css, html

I have texts that most of the time fit in a div, but sometimes it doesn't fit. There is no way to determine how many characters/words/paragraphs fit in the div, so I can't cut it off that way.

The div had a fixed height and width, so can we do something with that? Or do you have any suggestion how to get everything in the div, the correct way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the text isnt going to fit, you could use a css elipses to make it look a bit cleaner. Perhaps place the text in a hidden element and measure the height to see if you need to include a (more) link.

See http://mattsnider.com/css/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/

Comment: +1 will be interesting to see if `text-overflow` makes it into CSS3.

Comment: There is always jQuery for when it doesn't.  http://www.bramstein.com/projects/text-overflow/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I managed to get it working, but now, the cut offi s after 1 line of text (example: http://shup.com/Shup/324977/110328112012-Home-Roepingen-Mozilla-Firefox.png ). ANy suggestion?

Comment: @koko Can you link html instead of image?

Comment: @James This is the Url: http://www.toko01.be/nl/statisch/pagina/1/title/home
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something with that. Give the `div` in question an `overflow: hidden`. Then set the `div` height to some multiple of the `line-height` (this will depend on how many lines you want to show) so you make sure to not cut off the bottom portions of your text.

Comment: Does this work reliably? We tried it with line-heights of 18, but clipped text still appeared on the last line. Perhaps we did something wrong? It worked for a line-height of 20, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different overflow values in css, "auto" should cause a scrollbar to appear when text is bigger than the height/width will allow, or "hidden" to cut it off.

see: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html

Answer (score 0):

Using this class is the best way of solving such problem:

```
.truncate {
  width: 200px;      // Here you can also use ems as measure of width
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've written a truncate function in JavaScript that starts with the block of text and if it detects overflow `(scrollheight > height)` it starts removing words until it fits, then adds a "view more"
 link.