# jquery hide part of html code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a "news" page at the moment for a website.

I only want to display the first, let's say, 15 lines of each news, so that when you land on the page it looks nice.
At the end of the 15th line, I add a little link "read more" that calls a jquery hide/show function to display the rest of the news/article.

The problem is that the news content is stored as html in the database, and when I cut the first 15 lines, sometimes a div tag ends up not being closed properly, and it's messing up the jquery call. I tried different solutions, with running a function to close the unclosed tags etc, but there's always special cases where it's messing up.

Is there any solution to hide a part of a html tag purely based on height and without having to add an extra tag to show/hide the part that has to be hidden?

Comment: Are you looking for a Javascript or PHP solution?

Comment: 15 lines of contents? 15 lines can include html tags and that would be considered a line as well? Please explain like if your contents are inside a `<p>` or what?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725209/cut-off-text-before-read-more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [jQuery Expander Plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html).

Comment: Link is broken. Here git: https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-expander

Answer (score 3):

Set `overflow:hidden` on the container to hide the scrollbars and give it the desired `height`. (wrap the story in another container `div` if you need to)

Then when you click the "read more" button, simply remove the `height` style so that the entire story is shown.

Or better still, use a CSS class that you toggle on and off each time the button is clicked.

```
.shortstory{
    height:50px;
}

$(".readmorebutton").click(function(){
    $("selector for story container").toggleClass("shortstory");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using CSS to help. For example, assuming article markup looks like , you could have your CSS definition set at "max-height: 15em; overflow: hidden;", and then, just remove that 'max-height' property with JS when the link to 'read more' is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a class with `overflow:hidden` on your article you can simply use jQuery to toggle that class to show or hide more of the article.

css:

```
.overflow{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100px;
}
```

sample markup:

```
<div>
    <p class="overflow">
    </p>
    <span>Read More</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("someshowmorelink").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings("p").toggleClass("overflow");
});
```

[**Example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/VZyG8/)

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what I was looking for, I will try now and if it's working I come back and validate as the answer!

Comment: So in your example it works because the text contained in <p class="overflow"> is plain text, but mine has div, span and other html tags in it, and it messes up again... I dont understant why...

Comment: @Piero, if you could adjust the fiddle with some of your sample markup I can take a look at it and see what is causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

one way is you can show X number of characters : 
for eg: if my div height is 50px then use firebug and check how many characters it fits...then use substr (sub string) method and get that many characters only